# how can I change databases/files-binary path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, total.js

I want to create an `asar` file (I want to install my `total.js` web app in client pc, so I want to package with electron like an asar file) I need to redirect every directories have dynamic files like `databases\files-binary`.

So, how can I do that? I have some parameter in config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change default path where the files are saved.

You can:

- use `var nosql = DB.load('/path/to/database/file.nosql');` see docs https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#api~Database
- overwrite `Framework.prototype.nosql` to allow you to use different path that you define in config

  ```
  //config
  //db-directory  :/some/path/to/db-directory

  var Path = require('path');
  framework.nosql = function(name) {
      var self = this;
      var db = self.databases[name];
      if (db)
          return db;
      db = framework_nosql.load(name, Path.join(CONFIG('db-directory'), name));
      self.databases[name] = db;
      return db;
  };
  ```

Change the above code to fit your needs.

Now you can use nosql just like you would normaly do:

```
NOSQL('files').binnary.insert(...)  
// or in beta version 2.4.0 use 
NOBIN('files').insert(...)
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to accept my answer as correct.